# how to join two models in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two models as Project and Collaborator this is My tables

Project column

```
id
project_name
project_note
user_id
```

Collaborator Model

```
id
project_id
collaborator_id
```

I need join this models to get project_name instead project_id of Collaborator Model.

how can I do this. I read www.laravel.com documents but difficult to understand. help me in code...

```
project Model
<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{

     /*
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['project_name', 'project_notes', 'project_status', 'due_date'];

    public function scopePersonal($query)
{
     return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

}



    //
}

collaborator Model
<?php

namespace App;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;



class Collaboration extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'project_collaborator';

    /*
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['project_id', 'collaborator_id'];



     /*
     * Get the user that is a collaborator on another project
     * @return collection
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'collaborator_id');
    }


      /*
     * Query scope to return information about the current project
     * @param  $query
     * @param  int $id
     * @return query
     */
    public function scopeProject($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('project_id', $id);
    }

    public function scopeColabo($query)
{
     return $query->where('collaborator_id',Auth::user()->id);

}






}
```

Comment: What kind of relationship do you have between a *project* and a *collaborator*? One to many, one to one, etc.?

Comment: one to one relationship

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you need to add a relationship *hasOne* to your collaboration model:

```
class Collaboration extends Model
{
    .....
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Project');
    }
    .....
}
```

The method `project()` will define your relationship with your project model. And then you'll be able to get the collaboration project name like this:

```
$collaborations = Collaboration::with('project')->get();

foreach ( $collaborations as $collaboration ) {
    echo $collaboration->project->project_name;
}
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: where should I put **$collaborations = Collaboration::with('project')->get();**  in My blade view?

Comment: @Fernando no, this should be in you controller. This is making a request to the database and then you need to pass this data to the view to render it.

Comment: I did relationship to collaborator Model but got this error **ErrorException in ProjectCollaboratorsController.php line 287: Non-static method App\Collaboration::project() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context**    ProjectCollaboratorsController.php line 287  is this  ** public function getCollaborators($id)
    {
        $collaborators = Collaboration::project($id)->get(); //287
  
        return $collaborators;
    }**

Comment: @Fernando you can't do that. Read the documentation about relatioships and how to make queries.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Collaboration` class add the followoing relation:

```
public function project()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

And in your `User` class define a relation as:

```
public function collaborations()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Collaboration', 'collaborator_id');
}
```

Then you can get all the collaborations of logged in user by:

```
$collaborations = auth()->user()->collaborations()->with('project')->get()
```

or

To get all collaborations you can so as:

```
$collaborations = Collaboration::with('project')->get();
```

In your view file:

```
@foreach ($collaborations as $collaboration)
  {{ $collaboration->project->project_name }}
@endforeach
```